# Relative redirect using meta http-equiv="refresh" with gh-pages

Tags: html, redirect, github, github-pages

So i am trying to use the redirect meta tag on a web app hosted on Githubs gh-pages.

This is the tag I'm using; which works well on the local dev machine

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/angular/?layout=4#/app/home" /> <!--redirect-->
```

The problem is that gh-pages sites live on a URL like this

```
https://github.com/username/reponame
```

Which means that my redirect doesnt work because it drops the `reponame` for this:

```
https://github.com/username/angular/?layout=4#/app/home
```

obviously I could hardcode the repo name in the redirect tag but then this would mean that it wont work when im developing locally because the URL in the local dev doesnt include the repo name.

How should my meta tag be set up for this to work locally and on  gh-pages

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a relative url like `./angular/?layout=4#/app/home`.

Your redirect now reads :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=./angular/?layout=4#/app/home" />
```